# Veusz smooth curves

Tags: plot, veusz

I a using a dataset (a .csv format file) for plotting many graphs with Veusz.
I am getting a quite good result but the program merges my data points with segments and I would like something *smoother* (I don't know if this is the proper adjective here) like a curve.

Is there a way to do it? I cannot find this in my Veusz manual. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the line style and choosing bezier join?

Comment: Right. It did work! Thank you, my english wasn't enough good to understand the expression "bezier join".